# Switch files in variables (cpp)

Tags: c++, file, fstream

my Problem is best explained in code:

```
fstream One;
fstream Two;
fstream Three;
One.open(path1, ios_base::out);
Two.open(path2, ios_base::out);
Three.open(path3, ios_base::out);
```

As you can see above i have three fstream variables and I've loaded three seperate files into them.
Now I want to Change some files.

```
One=Three;
Three=Two;
```

So that when i use One file, i will be using file from path3.
I know that i probably can't assign fstreams like that. And here's my question: how can i do that?
Sorry for my english, if something is not clear then simply comment.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe pointer will help?

Comment: What is the use-case here? What is the actual problem you try to solve? Can't you just close the streams and re-open them with the other paths?

Comment: As Joachim asks, what's the use-case? My first guess would be that you might want to consider functions that accept an `fstream` reference and operate on those, and then pass the required fstream as a parameter.

Comment: You can [swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/swap), [or swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/swap2) two streams, but answering the `why` first may yield a better `how`

Comment: At some Point in my program I have to swap These streams so functions would write the Content to other files, the main reason why i want to do it as simple as i can is that the code is rewritten from fortran and it's a big wall of text.

Comment: @Kuker can't you factor out the processing to a different function and just switch around the order of your arguments?

Comment: Also in my Program These fstream variables are used globally as structs, that's why i want them modified.

Comment: @TartanLlama As i explained before, I would then have to Change whole program, it was written in the 80's so no classes or OOP is used (which means changing EVERY time the function is called)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    auto path1 = "a.txt";
    auto path2 = "b.txt";
    auto path3 = "c.txt";

    ofstream one;
    ofstream two;
    ofstream three;
    one.open(path1);
    two.open(path2);
    three.open(path3);

    swap( one, two );
    two << "Two" << endl;
}
```

Things to note:

- Use `ofstream` for pure output streams.
- Don't use global variables.
- Ideally *check for failures* (not done in the above code).

Comment: Isn't this available only in C++11 ?

Comment: @fjardon: Yes, you need a modern compiler. The current C++ standard is C++14.

Comment: Too bad that i have to use global variables.. All fstreams are global.

Comment: @Kuker: You should ask a separate question about how to get rid of your global variables, outlining why you think you need them. They're not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pointers to refer to different `fstream` objects. I would suggest you to stay with stack allocation:

```
fstream One;
fstream Two;
fstream Three;
One.open(path1, ios_base::out);
Two.open(path2, ios_base::out);
Three.open(path3, ios_base::out);
```

And then you can use pointers like this:

```
fstream* A = &One;
fstream* B = &Two;
/*...*/
A = &Three;
```

I think this answers your question, but I think what you are really looking for is a way to use the same function with different `fstream`s. To do this, simply pass them as reference parameters:

```
void foo(fstream& fs){/*...*/}
```

And then call it with whatever `fstream` you like:

```
foo(A);
foo(B);
```

PS: and even if the `fstream`s are global variables (I would strongly suggest to change this) you can still pass them as parameters to functions.

Comment: I want to modify fstream variables as well, so I won't have to Change every function that uses These fstream variables

Comment: @Kuker This sounds like you are using global variables. Just dont do that, but pass references of the fstreams to the functions.

Comment: About those pointers, I did something like you said:
    `fstream* ptr1 = &One;
    fstream* ptr2;
    ptr1= &Two;`
But that still doesnt not make One == Two

Comment: @Kuker Sorry, but I am starting to get a bit annoyed. You should tell us what you actually want to achieve instead of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need two distinct references to the same file? If you need `One == Two` then just use `One` and `One` instead of `One` and `Two`